# How to get the number of request to the local server from the past 2 weeks using bash?

Tags: linux, bash

Im trying to write a bash script to get me the number of requests the local web server received on each of the previous 14 days.

The requests are listed @ /etc/httpd/logs/access_log

I was thinking in use a while loop to go trough each line, but don't know how to get the lines from the past 2 weeks.

I've figured out that you can change the format of the date command.

For example:

```
date +%d/%m/%Y
```

will return

```
03/12/2014
```

My Script:

```
#! /bin/bash requestsPast2weeks
cat /etc/httpd/logs/access_log
```

I don't know where to start this one. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It depends how did you set up your [rotation policy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html#rotation) for access log. Usually all files should be in /etc/httpd/logs/, but as I said it depends on your rotation policy.

And for counting number of requests you can use good old `wc`:

```
cat /etc/httpd/logs/access_log* | wc -l
```

If you want to find the number of requests per certain day (10/Jun/2013) use `grep`:

```
grep '\[10/Jun/2013' /etc/httpd/logs/access_log* | wc -l
```

And to find out what was the day 14 days ago use:

```
date  --date="14 days ago" +%d/%m/%Y
```

Now, put this into loop, and voilà ;-)

Comment: wc sees to work perfectly to count the requests, but I still dont know how to break the results per day, as the requirement, is to provide the number of requests per day for the past 2 weeks. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Depends on how are you defined the format for the names of rotated files.

Comment: Here are a couple of samples lines from cat /etc/httpd/logs/access_log

76.234.121.69 - - [10/Jun/2013:18:04:58 -0700] "GET /~igarcia6/images/BANNER3.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 20821 "http://hills.daterraweb.com/~igarcia6/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0"

76.234.121.69 - - [10/Jun/2013:18:04:58 -0700] "GET /~igarcia6/images/square.pic.png HTTP/1.1" 200 35577 "http://hills.daterraweb.com/~igarcia6/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0"

Comment: add the loop on your answer and so I can vote it up. It worked though. ;)

Comment: I hope that my answer helped you. That's my satisfaction. Points and acceptance are up to you :-)